# Duplicate Rows in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, duplicates, row

I have below view with one Column, "PositionDate".
I want to add a new column, "Currency" with Values "SEK", "EUR", "DKK" for every row.
Result should be 3 rows / positiondate with one Currency per row.

Current:

```
PositionDate
2017-04-11
2017-04-10
2017-04-09
```

Desired:

```
PositionDate    Currency
2017-04-11      SEK
2017-04-11      DKK
2017-04-11      EUR
2017-04-10      SEK
2017-04-10      DKK
2017-04-10      EUR
```

Thanks for first answers!
Now a new question.
Say I have below table. How do I pick up the latest previous value in case my joined table to not match the date and currency? On the null DKK value I want it to pick up 3. Note that dates do not exist every day since I do not load the tables on weekends.

```
Select
    PositionDate,
    Currency,
    T2.Value,
    isnull(t2.value, ? )
From t1
left join t2
on t1.currency = t2.Currency
and t1.PositionDate = t2.PositionDate
```

.

```
PositionDate    Currency        Value
2017-04-11      SEK               1
2017-04-11      DKK               NULL
2017-04-11      EUR               7
2017-04-10      SEK               4 
2017-04-10      DKK               3
2017-04-10      EUR               5
2017-04-07      SEK               4 
2017-04-07      DKK               3
2017-04-07      EUR               5
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [cross join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx) with a [table value constructor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382(v=sql.110).aspx) to do this:

```
SELECT  v.PositionDate, c.Currency
FROM    dbo.YourView AS v
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('SEK'), ('EUR'), ('DKK')) AS c (Currency);
```

**[Example on DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=050764abe23a0b06ff0312742b5b99e0)**

If you have your currencies stored in a table, then you can use this table instead of a table value constructor:

```
SELECT  v.PositionDate, c.Currency
FROM    dbo.YourView AS v
CROSS JOIN dbo.Currency AS c;
```

Comment: Thanks! Did you see my new question?

Comment: If you have a new question, you should post it as a new question. You can always link back to this one for reference, but since this question has been answered, it is unlikely to attract new visitors to the page, so you will get a better response by posting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cross apply

```
;with dte(a)
as
(
select '2017-04-11' union all
select '2017-04-10' union all
select '2017-04-09')
select * from dte c 
cross apply
(
 values('skk'),
       ('dkk'),
       ('ekk')
) b(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

With all values hard-coded:

```
    select p.PositionDate, c.Currency 
    from (values('2017-04-11'), ('2017-04-10'), ('2017-04-09')) as P([PositionDate])
    cross join (values('skk'), ('dkk'), ('ekk')) c(Currency)
```